# fixing the url from the string using replace

Tags: coldfusion

I am doing a cfhttp call using a cfx_http5 tag as it is faster and better than cfhttp. so the links are coming as:

```
<a href="/e9.asp?rpttype=298&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2">sort A</a>
```

so i add the following script using the replace

```
http://mysubdomain.domain.com/http://mysubdomain.domain.com/e9.asp?rpttype=298&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2

<cfset lnk = ReplaceNoCase(objget, 'href="', 'href="http://mysubdomain.domain.com/', 'all')>
```

in few of the links, it is coming as correct but in few of the links it is coming as above appending one more to the already existing one,

so i want to make it conditional, if it exists, do not append or add or else add if there is no link

any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Share some code and tell us why what you tried is not giving the expected results.

Comment: my try is the replace code which i adding to the missing links, now it is already appending to the links which are there, so i am not sure @ this point where to move

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regular expressions` with `negative lookahead` like this:

```
<cfset lnk = reReplaceNoCase(objget, 'href=\"(?!http\:\/\/)','href="http://mysubdomain.domain.com', 'ALL')>
```

This will work for both type of links.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a conditional if statement

```
lnk = 'http://mysubdomain.domain.com/e9.asp?rpttype=298&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2';
if (!findNoCase('mysubdomain.domain.com', lnk)) {
  lnk = ReplaceNoCase(objget, 'href="', 'href="http://mysubdomain.domain.com/', 'all');
}
```

Comment: A `/` in the end of the replace with string is not needed.

Comment: If you look at the sample URL he has provided, there is already a `/` before the URL.